# How can I create a custom metabox in wordpress with out creating plugin?

Tags: wordpress, performance, meta-boxes

Most of the cases a plugin is created and  the code for the metabox . Its very lengthy code and its not able to access the metabox with out plugin activation. The number of plugin per site reduce the perfomance of the site. Please help

Comment: A plugin or theme is the only way unless you want to modify the actual wordpress code, which I would not recommend.

Comment: Now I understand the wordpress coding standards and methods..We can create any thing with the help of plugins or else we can add the code directly to the `function.php`. But the best way is writing plugin instead of modifying the core files. Thanks for the help any way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paste below code into function.php of your active theme in word press.it will create custom meta box:

```
/*Create custom MetaBox*/
function CreateTextfield()
{
$screen = 'post';
add_meta_box('my-meta-box-id','Text Editor','displayeditor',$screen,'normal','high');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'CreateTextfield' ) ;

/*Display PostMeta*/
function displayeditor($post)
{
global $wbdb;
$metaeditor = 'metaeditor';
$displayeditortext = get_post_meta( $post->ID,$metaeditor, true );  
?>
<h2>Secound Editor</h2>
<label for="my_meta_box_text">Text Label</label>
    <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text" id="my_meta_box_text" value="<?php echo $displayeditortext;?>" />
   <?php        
}

/*Save Post Meta*/
function saveshorttexteditor($post)
{
$editor = $_POST['my_meta_box_text'];
update_post_meta(  $post, 'metaeditor', $editor);
}
add_action('save_post','saveshorttexteditor');
```

you can create and update postmeta by below code. you can add screen by create array in $screen.